# Custom ordering flow

Tags: 8, commerce, webforms

I was wondering if it's possible to replace the default commerce flow with my own custom flow.

As far as I know the default flow is following:

- Add individual products to cart on Product's detail page or in Products View
- Go to cart and proceed to checkout
- Add shipping & billing information
- Complete the payment

My flow need to be a bit different. I would like to create View of Products *(my products are entry-tickets for an attraction)* where user can select quantity of each Product he would like to purchase. I know this View can be AJAXified to change total price dynamically according to quantity of each product. When customer selects all tickets and quantities I need to send him to second page of my Multi-step webform where he enters shipping & billing information and finally confirms / fullfils the payment. After successful payment confirmation / fullfilment I'd like to display the third page of Multi-step Webform where is only confirmation and "thank you" message.

I've read through Commerce 2 documentation and I know how to change Order & Checkout workflows, but I'm not sure if I can use Multi-step Webform where the steps are following *(as described above)*:

- Step 1: Select quantities of each Product in Products View (10 products in total - ticket types)
- Step 2: Fill shipping and billing information
- Step 3: Display confirmation message

The general idea is to skip the cart step where I need to go to cart page and instead realize whole flow as a 3-step Multi-step Webform.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To skip the cart part of the checkout flow, I have been [using the patch here](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/2810723). This is the leading patch for decoupling the cart from Commerce (it's a bit hard-wired at present).

If you want to customize the checkout flow with more steps, you can write a custom [checkout flow plugin](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/checkout/create-custom-checkout-flow).

To add a custom confirmation message, you can [write a checkout pane](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/checkout/create-custom-checkout-pane).

Comment: Yes, thanks. I've already looked at "Custom checkout flow". But the checkout doesn't need to change, it can remain single step. I want to create multistep form from "Products view" and "Checkout" and "Confirmation" message.

Comment: @PatrickStar Commerce usually includes a "Confirmation" message as part of the checkout flow.  If you want something special, you can write a checkout pane; I added a link to my answer.

Comment: and is it possible to create custom ordering Form from Products View and use EventSubscribers or Commerce API to add / remove Products from Cart? And finally after clicking button "Proceed to checkout" redirect from this form to Checkout page?

Comment: Have you tried to do any of this yet? Where did you get stuck? Yes you can customize the Commerce order form. And I already linked to a patch for skipping checkout. There are a variety of other ideas for redirecting straight to payment info input in the linked issue.

Comment: I'm trying to find best solution if there's any before making unnecessary mistakes. I'll try your recommendations and update the question if necessary.

Comment: @PatrickStar Questions on Drupal Answers should ideally have a single answer; broad questions that invite discussion are off topic for this site. If you want to chat in general about Commerce implementations, you should join the Commerce Slack channel, where you can talk directly to the Commerce developers: https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/getting-started/getting-help